# Problem with displaying stuff with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Essentially I want to have a rectangle moving around the screen via the wasd keys. The window pops up and then promptly closes out and I cannot figure out why. I cannot figure out how this is different from my other image - displaying code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

X = 1000
Y = 800

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))

pygame.display.set_caption('Image')

def main():
    px = X/2
    py = Y/2

    while True:
        display_surface.fill(white)

        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            py += 5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            px -= 5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            py -= 5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            px += 5

        pygame.draw.rect(display_surface, black, (px, py, 25, 25))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You're not calling `main()`.  Also the WASD event handling is in the wrong spot.  Handle the event `pygame.KEYDOWN` and put it under there.  But maybe you want to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` instead.

Comment: I was going to use pygame.key_pressed but couldn't find a list of all the Boolean values it returned (for example, what is the index for 'w'?) also I thought main was automatically called?

Comment: It returns a dictionary of all keys.  e.g.: `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()`
    `if keys[pygame.K_w]:`.  Every valid PyGame key is in there as a True/False value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run `main()`

To move object it can be better to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. With `event` you would have to press key again and again or write it in different way.

With `get_pressed()` you have to use `if`, not `elif` bacause it can have `True` for many keys at the same time.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

X = 1000
Y = 800

display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y))

pygame.display.set_caption('Image')

def main():
    px = X/2
    py = Y/2

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            #elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:                
            #    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            #        py += 5

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            py -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            px -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            py += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            px += 5

        display_surface.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(display_surface, black, (px, py, 25, 25))
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```